# I need to generate a sequence of 20 random values between 0 and 99 in an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need to generate a sequence of 20 random values between 0 and 99 in an array. I need to print the sequence, sort it, and print the sorted sequence. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class  Loop20{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int array[]=new int[20];
        System.out.println("The Random Numbers are: ");
        for (int i=0; i < array.length ; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(99);
            System.out.println(array[i]);            
        }    

    }
}
```

Thank-You!

Comment: Where are you stuck? Sorting?

Comment: Yes, I tried Arrays.sort but I don't know where to go from there!

Comment: Show your sorting code, and explain the problem you are having with sorting.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I am supposed to sort the numbers the code generates into ascending order. I don't even know where to start. Arrays.sort(array[i]);
 
System.out.println("Sorted String Array");
for (String str : array[i]) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

Comment: @KatieKrueger have you tried google?  There should be a wealth of examples (depending on your programming language) that should show sorting (ascending or descending) in any language, just takes a little searching.

Comment: But you do know where to start, you said so yourself - `Arrays.sort`.  Add that code that you said you tried to your sample code above, and explain the problem you are having with it.

Comment: Arrays.sort(array[i]);
 
System.out.println("Sorted String Array");
for (String str : stringArray) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

Comment: You're doing fine: 1) declare the arrays, 2) FIRST LOOP: fill them with random numbers and print, 3) Sort, 4) SECOND LOOP: just like the first one, except print only.  You also know about "Array.sort()": cool!  SUGGESTION: Google for a few "Array.sort()" examples, like this one: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: And what happened when you ran that code?

Answer (score 1):

After you fill the array with the random numbers, run some sort of sorting function (your choice) on it.

Lastly, have another for loop that is the printing piece, which looks really similiar to what you have in the other for loop.

Hope that helps without just giving you a code block that does it, it lets you have some fun looking up some of the pieces :)

Comment: "Don't do your print in the first for loop you have." - The requirements are to print it twice - once before sorting, once after.

Comment: I misread the requirements XD.  The OP seems to be on the right track then.  Removed that piece :)